# Set default template for Joomla without admin panel

Tags: joomla, admin

I am trying to understand which configuration files does Joomla use to store info about its default template. Is there a possibility to install template and set it by default just modifying htdocs files and not using admin panel?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is stored in the database, not a file. If you want to change it manually, you will have to write a database query. To install a template, you need to go through the admin panel, unless you want to write some complex query to make Joomla discover it. What's wrong with using the admin panel anyway? It's 10x quicker and what you want to do is simply time consuming

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted to get some clarity on this point

Answer (score 4):

Joomla **default** template value is stored in database not files.

You could change table `#__template_styles` and set value `1` in the field `home` to make a template default.

Hope this helps